# Error while taking backup

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I need to take a backup of a database in MySQL. So I have written a query as:

```
mysqldump -u root -p pwd123 r_mysql > BackupHRM2.sql
```

For this I am getting an error saying

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'mysqldump -u root -p pwd123 r_mysql > BackupHRM2.sql' at line 1
```

Please could someone help me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqldump` is a command line utility. You are supposed to run it directly from your shell, not inside a `mysql` session. It's not an SQL command.

If you're using phpMyAdmin, look for backup options there. (Look at [How to backup your Mysql database with phpMyAdmin](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php) for instance.)

Comment: I am new to MySql i don't know this terminaligies. Actually I am using the "phpMyAdmin". In phpmyadmin--->selected the "SQL" option. Then I got a text/edit area to enter my query. Is that wrong... If yes, what is the other way to execute my query...

Comment: I edited my answer, check that link and search google for "phpmyadmin" and "backup".

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 mysqldump -u root -ppwd123 r_mysql > BackupHRM2.sql
```

see there is **no gap** between `-p` and `PASSWORD`

If you are using PHPMyAdmin, backup from "Export" tab.

---

I am not very familiar with PHPMyAdmin, to import your backed up database just execute this from your command prompt (or Shell/Console).

```
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME < path/to/BackupHRM2.sql
```

Comment: Ya I have followed answer.. Now I am getting the error  as  import.php: Missing parameter: import_type (FAQ 2.8)
import.php: Missing parameter: format (FAQ 2.8)

Comment: this command is assumed to be executed from command prompt. If you are using phpMyAdmin, go to "Export" tab and save file will do the backup thingy for you.

Comment: Yes @Nishant your secont answer is right.... I got hte back up. And if possible could you teach me how to restore the database....